# Image upside down after picking image

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Im using `UIImagePickerController` for picking image from photo library. Im using landscape and portrait for editing images. When i pick a image it will displays correct orientation for portrait, but in landscape mode it displays upside down. I referred some code. But still it's not working. I referred this link [iphone : image captured from camera changes orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291344/iphone-image-captured-from-camera-changes-orientation)

code:

```
-(void)pick:(id)sender{


            imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

            imagePicker.delegate = self;

            imagePicker.allowsEditing =NO;

            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

            // imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;


            //  [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

            [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{


 newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];




     [newImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];

    [newImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[self.view addSubview:newImage];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

UIDeviceOrientation curDeviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    switch (curDeviceOrientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:

            NSLog(@"port");
             newImage.image = [ newImage.image imageRotatedByDegrees:0];
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
             newImage.image = [ newImage.image imageRotatedByDegrees:180];
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:

             NSLog(@"Left");
             newImage.image = [ newImage.image imageRotatedByDegrees:0];
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
             newImage.image = [ newImage.image imageRotatedByDegrees:90];
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp:
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
        default:
            break; // leave the layer in its last known orientation
    }

}

- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width, self.size.height)];

    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, DegreesToRadians(degrees));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-self.size.width / 2, -self.size.height / 2, self.size.width, self.size.height), [self CGImage]);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, it appears if you take a picture with the volume buttons pointed upward (the natural way, imo), the landscape image will display as upside down. This is due to the camera's sensor having no idea whether you have the phone in landscape left or landscape right. It is built on the assumption the "upright" direction is the one with volume buttons pointed downward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your class,

```
@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@implementation YOUR_CLASS

UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    imgPicker = [[NonRotatingUIImagePickerController alloc] init];
}

-(IBAction)clickForPhoto:(id)sender
{
    imgPicker.delegate = self;

    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Hopefully, this will help you.

Thanks.