# Displaying landscape images from camera roll xcode

Tags: xcode, camera, landscape, xcode4.5

I'm pulling images from the camera roll to display in my app, and portrait taken pictures work just fine, but landscape images get all funky smushed together.

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];        

displayPhoto.image = image;
```

I've figured out how to check the length and width of the pictures themselves, and therefore can do an if else statement to only rotate landscape pictures... but trying to find working code to actually rotate the images is difficult.  I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324130/iphoneimage-captured-from-camera-rotate-90-degree-automatically), but he's calling functions that don't exist, and clearly the code did not work for me :p.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

u have to use

```
      [displayPhoto setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```