# image is rotated after uploading to server?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a captured image from camera.I want to upload it server.I have got image from camera from below code

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let originalImage = (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!

    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 100) as NSData?

    if Constant.commonfunction.checkFileSize(fileData: imageData!)
    {
      let data = UploadData()
      data.fileName = "image.jpg"
      data.fileType = "Image"
      data.fileData = imageData as? Data
      data.mimeType = "image/jpg"
      arr_images.append(data)
      picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

        self.collectionView.reloadData()

      })

    }
    else
    {
        Constant.commonfunction.showAlertView(title: "Warning", message: "Please upload a file of size less than 10 MB", vc: self)
    }



  }
```

Please suggest the best solution.

Comment: try changing the mime type with image/jpeg and filename image.jpeg or try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 1)

Comment: does not work for me.i have already tried

Comment: try     imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 100) as NSData?
to imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 1)

Comment: what is 1 here  ?

Comment: compressionQuality.. it should be 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: does not work either

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324130/iphone-image-captured-from-camera-rotate-90-degree-automatically Hope it will sort your image rotating issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850184/ios-image-get-rotated-90-degree-after-saved-as-png-representation-data or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: @Andreas, problem is in EXIF orientation tag

Comment: @user28434 I don't see that being mentioned in the question at all.

Comment: @Andreas, it isn't, but problem in rotated image is in `EXIF` orientation tag, fixing it is the solution. If it would be mentioned in question, solution would be obvious and it won't be worth asking question at all.

Comment: @user28434 Perhaps you're confusing me with the OP. I'm not interested in an answer to his problem, I'm interested in understanding his problem. Telling me your solution to his problem doesn't help me with that.

Comment: The problem with this question: the title is asking about rotation, but the question seems to ask about how to upload an image: "I want to upload it server"

Comment: @Andreas, ah, yeah, editing is required then

Answer (score 0):

I was also having same issue but in objective C. hope this can help you.

check this file of objective C

[UIImage+Resize.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gnbr31tiprgpwe/UIImage%2BResize.h?dl=0)

[UIImage+Resize.m](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ubzppydfb44oqp/UIImage%2BResize.m?dl=0)