# How to rotate image in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am unable to rotate the image by 90 degrees in swift. I have written below code but there is an error and doesn't compile

```
  func imageRotatedByDegrees(oldImage: UIImage, deg degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    //Calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rotatedViewBox: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: oldImage.size.width, height: oldImage.size.height))
    let t: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degrees * CGFloat(M_PI / 180))
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t
    let rotatedSize: CGSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

    //Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    //Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    bitmap.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2, y: rotatedSize.height / 2)

    //Rotate the image context
    bitmap.rotate(by: (degrees * CGFloat(M_PI / 180)))

    //Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    bitmap.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    bitmap.draw(oldImage, in:  CGRect(origin: (x: -oldImage.size.width / 2,  y: -oldImage.size.height / 2, width:  oldImage.size.width, height: oldImage.size.height), size: oldImage.cgImage))

    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage

  }
```

below is the code i am not sure about

```
bitmap.draw(oldImage, in:  CGRect(origin: (x: -oldImage.size.width / 2,  y: -oldImage.size.height / 2, width:  oldImage.size.width, height: oldImage.size.height), size: oldImage.cgImage))
```

Comment: Manage the condition for image after capture from camera. And try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324130/iphone-image-captured-from-camera-rotate-90-degree-automatically It will help to sort out from the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33479054/291240

Comment: When  getting errors, never forget to tell people which ones they are!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is an extension of `UIImage` that targets **Swift 4.0** and can rotate just the image without the need for a `UIImageView`. Tested successfully that the image was rotated, and not just had its exif data changed.

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    func rotate(radians: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let rotatedSize = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
            .applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(radians)))
            .integral.size
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            let origin = CGPoint(x: rotatedSize.width / 2.0,
                                 y: rotatedSize.height / 2.0)
            context.translateBy(x: origin.x, y: origin.y)
            context.rotate(by: radians)
            draw(in: CGRect(x: -origin.y, y: -origin.x,
                            width: size.width, height: size.height))
            let rotatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return rotatedImage ?? self
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

To perform a 180 degree rotation, you can call it like this:

```
let rotatedImage = image.rotate(radians: .pi)
```

If for whatever reason it fails to rotate, the original image will then be returned.

Comment: This works, however the translation/origin seem to be wrong. The rotated image is shifted up and to the left :-/

Comment: @lenooh Can you post details on how you are calling it and some general details on the image?

Comment: CodeBender: I'm calling it with `let rotatedImage = image.rotate(radians: .pi)`. The image is 1433 × 2099. I then found another solution which works perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47402811/529663

Comment: As @lenooh points out. The accepted solution has several translation issues, 

The solution that seems to work for everyone is posted in his comment.    Here again for your convenience:  https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/47402811/529663

Answer (score 118):

set ImageView image

```
ImageView.transform = ImageView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

**Swift 5**

```
ImageView.transform = ImageView.transform.rotated(by: .pi)        // 180˚

ImageView.transform = ImageView.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)    // 90˚

ImageView.transform = ImageView.transform.rotated(by: .pi * 1.5)  // 270˚
```

Comment: Why M_PI_4? 90 degrees = M_PI_2

Comment: @JayeshMiruliya, also in Swift 3 you can use `CGFloat.pi` constant (divided by 2 ofc)

Comment: For **Swift 4** Use: `.pi/1` for 180˚  and `.pi/2` for 90˚

Comment: To rotate UIImage you may check this GitHub link. Working for Swift3. You may use ".pi/1 for 180˚ and .pi/2 for 90˚" for radians param as per above comment.     https://gist.github.com/norsez/e318d68f6a48786d35b3e7fd3b3a32ae

Comment: For animation - `UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
           self.needleImageView.transform = self.needleImageView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi/2))

        }`

Comment: perfect, easy, compact!

Answer (score 43):

In one line:

```
rotatedViewBox.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
```

Comment: This should be the best solution

Comment: Still the best solution in 2023

Answer (score 22):

```
 let angle =  CGFloat(M_PI_2)
  let tr = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: angle)
  ImageView.transform = tr
```

Comment: i want to rotate a UIImage not on imageview

Answer (score 17):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.0

```
dropDownImageView.transform = dropDownImageView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
```

If you want to add animation...

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
   self.dropDownImageView.transform = self.dropDownImageView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
})
```

Answer (score 9):

Rotate image via UIGraphics Context is comparatively heavy operation. The problems you may seen loosing quality and memory increase.

I suggest you should try to rotate the layer or view itself.

```
extension UIView {


    func rotate(degrees: CGFloat) {

        let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = { (degrees: CGFloat) in
            return degrees / 180.0 * CGFloat.pi
        }
        self.transform =  CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreesToRadians(degrees))

        // If you like to use layer you can uncomment the following line 
        //layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(degrees), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    }
}
```

How to use

```
yourImageView.rotate(degrees: 40)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the code below for Swift 3:

```
extension UIImage {

func fixImageOrientation() -> UIImage? {
    var flip:Bool = false //used to see if the image is mirrored
    var isRotatedBy90:Bool = false // used to check whether aspect ratio is to be changed or not

    var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    //check current orientation of original image
    switch self.imageOrientation {
    case .down, .downMirrored:
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI));

    case .left, .leftMirrored:
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2));
        isRotatedBy90 = true
    case .right, .rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-M_PI_2));
        isRotatedBy90 = true
    case .up, .upMirrored:
        break
    }

    switch self.imageOrientation {

    case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.width, y: 0)
        flip = true

    case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: self.size.height, y: 0)
        flip = true
    default:
        break;
    }

    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), size: size))
    rotatedViewBox.transform = transform
    let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    bitmap!.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2.0, y: rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    var yFlip: CGFloat

    if(flip){
        yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
    } else {
        yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
    }

    bitmap!.scaleBy(x: yFlip, y: -1.0)

    //check if we have to fix the aspect ratio
    if isRotatedBy90 {
        bitmap?.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.height / 2, width: size.height,height: size.width))
    } else {
        bitmap?.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.height / 2, width: size.width,height: size.height))
    }

    let fixedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return fixedImage
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not that far off from functional.  You can apply the transform as you are doing directly to the bitmap, you don't need an intermediate view:

```
func imageRotatedByDegrees(oldImage: UIImage, deg degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let size = oldImage.size

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    let bitmap: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    //Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    bitmap.translateBy(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    //Rotate the image context
    bitmap.rotate(by: (degrees * CGFloat(M_PI / 180)))
    //Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    bitmap.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    let origin = CGPoint(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.width / 2)

    bitmap.draw(oldImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))

    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Also, if you're going to create a function that rotates an image, it is typically good form to include a `clockwise: Bool` parameter that will interpret the `degrees` argument as rotating clockwise or not.  The implementation and appropriate conversion to radians I leave to you.

Also note that it's a bit hand-wavy on my part to assume that `oldImage.size` is non-zero.  If it is, force-unwrapping `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!` will probably crash.  You should validate the `oldImage`'s size and if it's invalid just return `oldImage`.

Comment: While functional, this code will not rotate the image about the center unless in the unique scenario that the image is square. I used the intermediate method and it produced about-center rotation.

Answer (score 2):

You can first set your image in imageView and rotate get your image in imageView

Here:

```
let customImageView = UIImageView()
customImageView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, w: 250, h: 250)
customImageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")

customImageView .transform = customImageView .transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.init(M_PI_2))
var rotatedImage = UIImage()
rotatedImage = customImageView.image!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use non-existing initializer for CGRect. If you want to use **CGRect(origin:size:)**, then create origin properly, without width and height parameters. Or remove size parameter and use **CGRect(x:y:width:height:)**.

Just replace this line

```
bitmap.draw(oldImage, in:  CGRect(origin: (x: -oldImage.size.width / 2,  y: -oldImage.size.height / 2, width:  oldImage.size.width, height: oldImage.size.height), size: oldImage.cgImage))
```

with this one:

```
let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: -oldImage.size.width / 2,  y: -oldImage.size.height / 2), size: oldImage.size)
bitmap.draw(oldImage.cgImage!, in: rect)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want specific rotation and like to use all orientations one by one.

```
func rotateImage() -> UIImage {
    let newOrientation = Orientation(rawValue: self.imageOrientation.rawValue + 1) ?? UIImage.Orientation(rawValue: 0)
    return UIImage(cgImage: self.cgImage!, scale: self.scale, orientation: newOrientation!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: bitmap.width, height: bitmap.height))
UIImage(cgImage: oldImage.cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: .leftMirrored).draw(at: .zero)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
```

Much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

To start spinning a image view:

```
func startSpinning()  {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.gearImageView!.transform = self.gearImageView!.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
    })
}
```

To stop spinning:

```
func stopSpinning()  {
    self.gearImageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution is to rotate the **UIImage**

**1. Create an extension for UIImage**

```
extension UIImage {
 
    /// Rotate the UIImage
    /// - Parameter orientation: Define the rotation orientation
    /// - Returns: Get the rotated image 
   func rotateImage(orientation: UIImage.Orientation) -> UIImage {
      guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return UIImage() }
      switch orientation {
           case .right:
               return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: .up)
           case .down:
               return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: .right)
           case .left:
               return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: .down)
           default:
               return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: .left)
       }
   }
}
```

**2. Use it around your code**

- Your UIImage

`image.rotateImage(orientation: .up)`

Comment: `cgImage` property might return `nil`. You should change your return type to optional and return `nil`. Btw you should use the original image `scale` property to preserve its scale.

Answer (score -1):

```
ImageView?.transform = transform.rotated(by: (CGFloat(Double.pi / 2)))
```

Swift 4.2

Rotation - right. Works fine.