# Rotating UIImage for Google ML Vision framework on Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, apple-vision

When an image gets captured it defaults to left orientation. So when you feed it into the `textDetector` inside the `Google Vision framework`, it comes all jumbled, unless you take the photo oriented left (home button on the right). I want my app to support both orientations.

[image]

```
let visionImage = VisionImage(image: image)

self.textDetector?.detect(in: visionImage, completion: { (features, error) in
    //2
    guard error == nil, let features = features, !features.isEmpty else {
        print("Could not recognize any text")
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    //3
    print("Detected Text Has \(features.count) Blocks:\n\n")
    for block in features {
    //4
        print("\(block.text)\n\n")
    }
})
```

I have tried to recreate the Image with a new orientation and that won't change it.

Does anyone know what to do?

I have tried all of these suggestions
[How to rotate image in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882487/how-to-rotate-image-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try normalizing the UIImage object, using this function:

```
import UIKit

public extension UIImage {    
    public func normalizeImage() -> UIImage {
        if self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up {
            return self
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))

        let normalizedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return normalizedImage
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, cause I usually use this whenever there's an orientation problem.