# Swift - randomly rotate UIImageView in 3 directions (top, right or bottom)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm very new to `Swift` and really need some help out here.
I have a `UIImageView` with the image of arrow on it. I want the arrow to randomly change its direction on a button click in only THREE directions: top, right and bottom.
I figured out to rotate the `UIImageView` using `CGAffineTransform`, but how can I ?

1. Exclude the left direction from the rotation?
2. Make the arrow change its direction (top, right and bottom) randomly
   ?

[here's a screen I work with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F74Vw.png)

Comment: Please share your attempts so far

Comment: Well, I came up with a thought to create an Enum RotationDirection with three cases: top, right, bottom. And I also have a line of code for CGAffineTransform which doesn't have any connection with the Enum so far. self.arrowImageView.transform = self.arrowImageView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat((Double.pi / 2)))
This line of code finely rotates the image in the UIImageView, but in all 4 directions (obviously). And here I stuck ;)

Comment: Kindly refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882487/how-to-rotate-image-in-swift This might help you in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will helps you:

```
    let degree = [Double.pi / 2, Double.pi, Double.pi * 2]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(degree.count)))
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(degree[randomIndex]))
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. The only one thing is why the arrow doesn't change its rotation on EVERY tap? Sometimes it stands still even after the button click...

Comment: @Dary coz it is selecting random value from array.

Comment: So by this logic sometimes the direction just stays the same, that's why there's no rotation on a button click. Is that the case?

Comment: Thank you very much! The last question to you though :) The arrow in your example still rotates to the left direction. However, I need to exclude this direction from the rotation. How can I do this?

Comment: @Dary remove first object from array.

Comment: @Dary could you please approve and upvote my answer if it helps you. This will also helps other to find correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

generate a random nuumber:

```
 let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<3)

  switch randomInt {
    case 0:
        rotateRight()
    case 1:
        rotateUp()
    case 2:
        rotateDown()
    default:
        rotateWhatever()
    }
```