# How to rotate image in proper orientation

Tags: ios, swift, cgimage

I'm Capturing image and storing it in NSData format. When i capture my image in portrait device orientation, the image is rotating left 90 degrees. when i'm capturing image in landscape device orientation, i'm getting image in proper manner. i trying below function. but i don't know what cgImage need to take as CGImage.

```
func rotateImageProperly(image:UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let normalImage:UIImage!

    if(image.imageOrientation == .up) {
        normalImage = image
    }else if (image.imageOrientation == .left){
        normalImage = UIImage(cgImage: <#T##CGImage#>, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
    }


    return normalImage
}
```

Comment: `image.cgImage!`, I suppose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate image in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882487/how-to-rotate-image-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code to properly rotate image :

```
func imageOrientation(_ src:UIImage)->UIImage {
    if src.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up {
        return src
    }
    var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    switch src.imageOrientation {
    case UIImageOrientation.down, UIImageOrientation.downMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: src.size.width, y: src.size.height)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        break
    case UIImageOrientation.left, UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: src.size.width, y: 0)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        break
    case UIImageOrientation.right, UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: src.size.height)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        break
    case UIImageOrientation.up, UIImageOrientation.upMirrored:
        break
    }

    switch src.imageOrientation {
    case UIImageOrientation.upMirrored, UIImageOrientation.downMirrored:
        transform.translatedBy(x: src.size.width, y: 0)
        transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        break
    case UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored, UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
        transform.translatedBy(x: src.size.height, y: 0)
        transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
    case UIImageOrientation.up, UIImageOrientation.down, UIImageOrientation.left, UIImageOrientation.right:
        break
    }

    let ctx:CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(src.size.width), height: Int(src.size.height), bitsPerComponent: (src.cgImage)!.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: (src.cgImage)!.colorSpace!, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!

    ctx.concatenate(transform)

    switch src.imageOrientation {
    case UIImageOrientation.left, UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored, UIImageOrientation.right, UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored:
        ctx.draw(src.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: src.size.height, height: src.size.width))
        break
    default:
        ctx.draw(src.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: src.size.width, height: src.size.height))
        break
    }

    let cgimg:CGImage = ctx.makeImage()!
    let img:UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)

    return img
}
```

Usage :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){
    var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    image = self.imageOrientation(image)
}
```

Comment: Its not working buddy, when i capture image in portrait mode, white blank image is storing in my gallery :(

Comment: Ohh can you share more code? your question doesn't really tell the main problem then,