# How to rotate GMSMapView?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

My google mapView is not rotating according to my device orientation. Wondering how can I make it rotate accordingly?

I'm using the following to detect orientation changes. The landscape is being detected but I want to be able to make the map rotate too. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

@objc func rotated() {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            print("Landscape orientation")
        } else {
            print("Portrait orientation")
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882487/how-to-rotate-image-in-swift

Comment: but I have a GMSMapView not imageView, how am I going rotate it?